# pass information from a click event that is inside a Foreach to a variable

Tags: javascript, foreach, onclick

I want to get the value of "indx" generated by the for each to store it in a variable and use it globally in another operation. aid

```
<>
let table = ``;
 
await viewData.forEach((category, indx) => {
      table +=    `

         <div >
       <li  key="${indx}" onclick="(console.log(${indx}))" class="list-group-item"  > 
       ${category.name}
       </li></div>
       `

    });
    evento.innerHTML = table;
      `<div class="category">
    <ul class="list-group"">${table}</ul>
    </div>
    `
</>
```

Comment: Does it work? Did you check if it's injected into the final HTML?

Comment: You can't `await` a `forEach` statement (it doesn't return a promise), and you're better off using [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) rather than adding inline JS to your markup. Attach a listener to the `<ul>` (why do you call that variable "table"?) and then have that watch for events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

Comment: Create a global variable: `let globalIndx;` and store the value in it: `globalIndx = indx;`

Answer (score 0):

When you dynamically generate html and we cannot pass objects directly from the generation logic to the runtime, however we can easily hookup callbacks that pass *identifiers* or *index values* to our javascript functions that at runtime can use the value to lookup the original object reference.

[This example](https://jsfiddle.net/qs237bLk/1/) extends the original post and uses the *index*:

```
let table = ``;

let viewData = [{name: 'Item1', Id: 1},{name: 'Item2', Id: 2}];

viewData.forEach((category, indx) => {
      table +=    `

         <div >
       <li  key="${indx}" onclick="(categoryClicked(${indx}))" class="list-group-item"  > 
       ${category.name}
       </li></div>
       `

    });
    
var evento = document.getElementById('evento');
evento.innerHTML = table;
      `<div class="category">
    <ul class="list-group"">${table}</ul>
    </div>
    `;
    
var categoryClicked = function (indx) {
    // passed in index
    console.log(indx);
    
    // lookup the category from the viewData so we can access other properties
    let category = viewData[indx];
    console.log(category);
}
```

Using the index is generally not recommended, index is a volatile link that can easily be affected by sorting, filtering or other mutating operations against the array source. Your solution will be more robust if you use an *identifier* from the element in the array: *[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qs237bLk/2/)*

```
let table = ``;

let viewData = [{name: 'Item1', Id: 1},{name: 'Item2', Id: 2}];

viewData.forEach((category) => {
      table +=    `

         <div >
       <li  key="${category.Id}" onclick="(categoryClicked(${category.Id}))" class="list-group-item"  > 
       ${category.name}
       </li></div>
       `

    });
    
var evento = document.getElementById('evento');
evento.innerHTML = table;
      `<div class="category">
    <ul class="list-group"">${table}</ul>
    </div>
    `;
    
var categoryClicked = function (id) {
    // passed in index
    console.log(id);
    
    // lookup the category from the viewData so we can access other properties
    let category = viewData.find(cat => cat.Id === id);
    console.log(category);
}
```

> If you find yourself extensively generating code like this, you should transition over to a javascript templating framework like Handlebars.js, or something more robust like AngularJS/ReactJS/VuewJS

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: categoryClicked5 is not defined
    at HTMLLIElement.onclick (::1:1)

Comment: I have this error in the console after applying the solution

Comment: Look carefully at the brackets (parenthesis), looks like you missed them. Also play around in the fiddles, you will see they work there.